# Can't launch Rascal files in Eclipse: 'no such java method: org.rascalmpl.library.Prelude.remove'

Tags: eclipse, rascal

When trying to run any rascal file in eclipse (by right-clicking on file in Rascal Navigator and pressing `Run as → Rascal Application`), I get this error

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching Hello.rsc".
No such Java method:
org.rascalmpl.library.Prelude.remove(org.eclipse.imp.pdb.facts.ISourceLocation, /
org.rascalmpl.interpreter.IEvaluatorContext)
```

(`/` here used as a line separator.)

I haven't had this problem on this installation before.

```
java version:    1.7.0_65
Eclipse version: 4.2.2 (Juno)
Rascal version:  0.6.2.201312171007
```

### Update

It seems that there are more things that don't work.

If I import a standard module, like

```
import IO;
```

I get this error:

```
could not load module import IO;[No such Java method:
org.rascalmpl.library.Prelude.remove(org.eclipse.imp.pdb.facts.ISourceLocation, /
org.rascalmpl.interpreter.IEvaluatorContext)
```

And if I try to use the `syntax` construct:

```
module Syntax

start syntax Program = Expr;
...
[rest of syntax-declarations]
```

Then I get this error:

```
could not load module start syntax Program = Expr;[value(...) /
is not allowed in patterns
```

So it might be that the problem is more fundamental than simply not being able to run files/load them into the console.

Comment: Hi! This sounds more like a bug report to me! Could you submit it to github issues https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/issues ? BTW, it looks like something went wrong after an upgrade and a refresh, or quitting Eclipse and starting with the `-clean` option might solve the problem.

Comment: @jurgenv I tried to use `eclipse -clean`, it didn't seem to work. I've updated the question now; do you still think it is a bug, as opposed to for example a broken installation? If so I'll make it into an issue.

Comment: Looks like some complex interaction indeed. I guess it is a bug, but a rare one since it only happens if you have the Rascal project itself cloned and loaded and a much older installed version of a release. It may dissappear if you use the unstable release instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had rascal (git clone of [this repository](https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal.git)) as part of my workspace. I deleted that repository and now things seem to be back to normal (can load files into console etc.).